# Air in the stomach

Tags: newborn

We got premature twins that have a tube connected to their stomach. We use the tube to control the digestion and sometimes to feed them. When we suck the food from the stomach to see how much did they digest often a lot of air is coming out. Should we put the air to the stomach together with the food?

In other words, is air in the stomach a right thing?

Comment: Seems like a medical question to be asked your doctors.

Answer (score 6):

This one isn't so much parenting as medical:

I think you should probably ask the neo-natal folks at your hospital as with small prems it is critical to get things right until they have their strength up. Get fully qualified medical opinion on this.